# Need help: InvocationTargetException wrapped around "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [C" using CrudRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to execute a very simple query with Spring Data's CrudRepsitory and Hibernate.

Repo:

```
public interface LabelsAllRepository extends CrudRepository<LabelsAll, Integer>{

@Query("select distinct(a.kundentext1) from LabelsAll a where a.zeichnungsnummer= :zchnr and a.revision = :rev")
String findKtxt1ByZchnrAndRev(@Param("zchnr") String zchnr, @Param("rev") String rev);

}
```

I've tried many different ways to call that function but nothing helps. I always get  `InvocationTargetException` wrapped around `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [C`. Also theres no proper stack trace i think because i'm using reflection? I'm really not exactly sure.

```
@Override
public boolean isCounterForSet(String edvNb, String revision) {
    boolean ret = false;
    // This line is causing the exception to be thrown
    String labelsAll = labelsAllRepository.findKtxt1ByZchnrAndRev(edvNb, revision); 
    if (!labelsAll.equals("")) {
        int snCount = snCounterRepository.countSnByKtxt1(labelsAll);
        ret = (snCount != 0);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The query seems to be correct. `[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select distinct labelsall0_.kundentext1 as col_0_0_ from ascom_etiketten_all labelsall0_ where labelsall0_.zeichnungsnummer=? and labelsall0_.revision=?`

Could really use some help solving this problem.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace instead of a meaningless snippet of it. The snippet misses context and generally the real information is at the end or in some wrapped exception.

Comment: @M.Deinum There's no proper stacktrace because i've called the method using reflection and theres nothing wrong with the reflection itself. I use `System.out.println(ex.getCause().toString())` to get more information about it.

Comment: Which is a terrible way to do exception logging... If you are going to bypass a logger (which I highly recommend, or catch things yourself) at least do `ex.printStacktrace()`. Instead of only doing a toString on the exception as that will destroy all useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by entity class attribute defined as `char[]` instead of `String`. Hibernate therefore tried to cast `@Param("rev") String rev` to `char[]` which it couldn't do.